# JFrame Resizing (Distortion)

Tags: java, swing

I am utilizing Java Swing for the Design of a GUI.

Due to a change of Scope the Size of the GUI has to be changed. The GUI is currently developed under a `JFrame` class. However, I suspect that due to layout, `GroupLayout`, when I maximize the app, the components gets distorted.

Screenshot using `GroupLayout`:

[maximized]
http://s9.postimage.org/g8rmf03ql/Capture.png

[normal minimize]
http://postimage.org/image/oapd9590l/

bump

Comment: Got a couple of screen shots? Before/after

Comment: try using miglayout http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/whitepaper.html

Comment: You could prevent the user from resizing the window using jframe.setResizeable(false);

Comment: Or, use gridlayout or gridbaglayout. Sounds to me like your using the wrong layout

Comment: screen shots : http://postimage.org/image/4wf0x7v1n/

Comment: dangling: mig layout doesnt work unfortunately... it doesnt space my jcomponents propotionaly

imulsion: thank you, that was the initial idea however there was a change of scope

grid or gridbaglayout they're not working went through all the layouts...

Comment: @user1613606 I'd, personally, go for a `GridBagLayout` if you can. While I've not used it personally, `MigLayout` has good reputation

Comment: Did you try to [invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#invalidate()) the contentPane ?

Comment: gontard. no i did not.

just did some googling, how do i set it to invalidate on maximize?

Comment: With layout, the problem could be tricky. You should provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: yea... i don't think I could recreate the problem

Comment: I see a vertical `Box` in `BorderLayout.WEST`, a `JLabel` in `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `JPanel` in `BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: I think @trashgod is right. Could you confirm ?

Comment: Alternatively, check the [gaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).

Comment: That is only one screen-shot, and it does not  take 1000+ pixels width to show how it breaks.  But better to provide ASCII art or a drawing of how the GUI appears when small, and how it should appear when stretched vertically and horizontally, to show how extra space should be assigned.  By the looks of it, I'd put the column in the `LINE_START` of a `BorderLayout`, then create another panel with a `BorderLayout` and add it to the `CENTER`.  In the second panel, add the `Connection with Server..` in the `PAGE_START` and the `thank you..` in the CENTER.

Comment: updated the jframe in minimized state

Comment: @gontard 

I may be wrong however, I think the whole layout is in group layout. 
the Jpanel holds some frames which is utilizing card layout

Comment: @AndrewThompson updated the screenshots, the normal "non-minimize" http://postimage.org/image/oapd9590l/

Comment: OK.. so the end result of both those screenshots could be summed up with "..but the GUI stays in the top-left corner when expanded"?  Those two days would have been better spent investigating the layout I suggested, or **preparing ASCII art of how it *should* look**.  It is lucky you seem to have plenty of time on your hands.

Comment: @AndrewThompson

Thank you for all ur input so far... not really a gui person however appreciate the value of a good GUI. worked on other components the previous days.

in summary how i hope it will look like is that the Expanded(maximized) version to look like the minimized version

Comment: would add that i have no preference as long as it works... extra space can go... anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using BorderLayout. Here is the tutorial for Java BorderLayout.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

This is the easy way to arrange your components inside the JFrame.